# insert multiple rows into sql database at once through php input form

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to record the results of a car race, but I want to be able to enter all of the results for the race at once (rather than doing it one by one) but I just cannot seem to get it to work.

Code below:

INPUT FORM:

```
{
    $reID = $row['reID'];
    $racerID = $row['racerID'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$reID<input type='hidden' name='reID' value='$reID'>"; 
    echo "<td>$racerID<input type='hidden' name='racerID' value='$racerID'>"; 

    echo"<td><input type='text' name='rank'>";
    echo"<td><input type='text' name='timetaken'>";     

}
```

SQL INSERT FORM:

```
$rank=$_POST['rank'];
$timetaken=$_POST['timetaken'];
$reID=$_POST['reID'];
$racerID=$_POST['racerID']; 

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Racing (rank, timetaken, reID, racerID) VALUES ('$rank', '$timetaken', '$reID', '$racerID')");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

How this works is, I will select a race, then a specific event within that race, then that will display all the racers and I can enter their rank and time taken. At the same time the hidden inputs (racer no and raceevent will go into the database for each result too).

So I am trying to just enter all the ranks and timetaken for all racerIDs at once, can someone help me complete that please.

Thanks.

EXTRA:

```
$reID = $_GET['reID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM RaceEventRacer WHERE reID = $reID");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Comment: Make your code safer,  `$rank = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rank']);` Do the same with the other post params. Also if this is new code, you should use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

First of all u have to fix some issues with ur php form generation...

all of ur input elements are going to have the same name attribute...
correct it first

-use something like this

```
$cv=0;

while () {

    .......................
    .......................
    echo "<input name='racer_'.$cv>";  // in each repetition new name value, not the same



    $cv++;
}
```

Comment: can u post the html page that contains the submit form;
a post array is generted when u submit the page(save). it can track using firebug or some other tool

Comment: this is the raw php code( just a part of the code, u may have some looping also ex- for)

please post ur full code or complete generated html output (copy it from the browser, not from the raw source code)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having name='reID' you should have name='reID[]', the same withthe other fields. And the future code would look like this:

```
$ranks = $_POST['rank'];
$timetakens = $_POST['timetaken'];
$reIDs = $_POST['reID'];
$racerIDs = $_POST['racerID']; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO Racing (rank, timetaken, reID, racerID) VALUES";
$values = array();
foreach($ranks as $key => $rank) {
    $values[] = "('$rank', '{$timetakens[$key]}', '{$reIDs[$key]}', '{$racerIDs[$key]}')";
}
$sql .= implode(', ', $values);
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
```